# SQLite Trigger: Update a table after insert is done on another

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, triggers

I have three main tables to keep track of `products`, `location` and the `logistics` between them which includes moving products to and from various locations. I have made another table `balance` to keep a final balance of the quantity of each product in respective locations.

Here are the schemas:

```
products(prod_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
         prod_name TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
         prod_quantity INTEGER NOT NULL,
         unallocated_quantity INTEGER)
```

Initially, when products are added, prod_quantity and unallocated_quantity have the same values. unallocated_quantity is then subtracted from, each time a certain quantity of the respective product is allocated.

```
location(loc_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
         loc_name TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL)

logistics(trans_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
          prod_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
          from_loc_id INTEGER NULL,
          to_loc_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
          prod_quantity INTEGER NOT NULL,
          trans_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
          FOREIGN KEY(prod_id) REFERENCES products(prod_id),
          FOREIGN KEY(from_loc_id) REFERENCES location(loc_id),
          FOREIGN KEY(to_loc_id) REFERENCES location(loc_id))

balance(prod_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        loc_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        quantity INTEGER NOT NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY(prod_id) REFERENCES products(prod_id),
        FOREIGN KEY(loc_id) REFERENCES location(loc_id))
```

At each entry made in `logistics`, I want a trigger to update the values in `balance` thereby keeping a summary of all the transactions (moving products between locations)

I thought of a trigger solution which checks if for each insert on the table `logistics`, there already exists the same `prod_id, loc_id` entry in the `balance` table, which if exists will be updated appropriately. However, I don't have the experience in SQLite to implement this idea.

Comment: Read [sqlite-trigger](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-trigger/)

Comment: @stovfl I have read the documentation and have written a trigger for updating the unallocated_quantity values. but I seem to be lost for the problem I mentioned here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your TRIGGER would be along the lines of either :-

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS logistics_added AFTER INSERT ON logistics
BEGIN
    UPDATE balance SET quantity = ((SELECT quantity FROM balance WHERE prod_id = new.prod_id AND loc_id = new.from_loc_id) - new.prod_quantity) WHERE prod_id = new.prod_id AND loc_id = new.from_loc_id;
        UPDATE balance SET quantity = ((SELECT quantity FROM balance WHERE prod_id = new.prod_id AND loc_id = new.to_loc_id) + new.prod_quantity) WHERE prod_id = new.prod_id AND loc_id = new.to_loc_id;
END;
```

or :-

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS logistics_added AFTER INSERT ON logistics
BEGIN
    INSERT OR REPLACE INTO balance VALUES(new.prod_id,new.from_loc_id,(SELECT quantity FROM balance WHERE prod_id = new.prod_id AND loc_id = new.from_loc_id) - new.prod_quantity);
        INSERT OR REPLACE INTO balance VALUES(new.prod_id,new.to_loc_id,(SELECT quantity FROM balance WHERE prod_id = new.prod_id AND loc_id = new.to_loc_id) + new.prod_quantity);
END;
```

Note that the second relies upon adding a UNIQUE constraint to the **balance** table by using `PRIMARY KEY (prod_id,loc_id)` or alternately `UNIQUE (prod_id,loc_id)`. The UNIQUE constraint would probably be required/wanted anyway.

The subtle difference is that the second would INSERT a balance row if and appropriate one didn't exist. The latter would do nothing if the appropriate balance row didn't exist.

Comment: i had tried something similar to the first method, but got stuck in syntactical errors. My current implementation just got rid of the balance table and uses an INNER JOIN on logistics to generate the balance. Thanks though!